# AllowOverride None in /var/www/ result in bad performance

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have read in an article that its better to set "**AllowOverride None for /**"     **"AllowOverride None for /var/www/"** for security reason and based on that i have changed configuration to the following.Is it true that if we set “**Allowoverride All for /var/www/**” then a request for index.html apache looks for .htaccess inside /.htaccess /www/.htaccess etc.Which reduces performance,for that i set "**Allowoverride None for /**" and "**Allowoverride All for /var/www/**"

**DocumentRoot /var/www

```
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options  FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>**
```

But After changing this performance reduced Badly, spawning of child process sky rocketed, for few client requests ,but changing "AllowOverride to None on /var/www "fixed the issue...Can you give me an explanation to Allowoverride issue.

Comment: Do you need to use .htaccess files for some reason?  If not, then don't set `AllowOverride to anything other than `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Including your configuration in the virtual host definition should have better impact on performance than including so many `.htaccess` files here and there. However, I don't think that just enabling `AllowOverride` and even including few `.htaccess` files will cause a considerable/noticeable performance degradation.

Comment: we dont use any .htaccess file so changed Allowoveride to None on / and None on /var/www .but after that we have noticed spawning of too many child process even if clients were very few..Changing it back to All on /var/www/ fixed the issue